# How do I choose which column from the "foreign" table is displayed in the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I am building a simple ASP.NET MVC app with Entity Framework Database First that allows a user to edit tables in a database. One table has a foreign key to another table. I want the user to be able to change the foreign key value.

**My question:** How do I choose which column from the "foreign" table is displayed to the user in the view? I scaffolded the view out, but it is displaying the wrong column.

The foreign key is in the DealerAuto table, which has columns: DealerAutoID, DealerID, DealerMakeName, DealerModelName. For some reason, the dropdown in the view for DealerAutoID is pulling in DealerMakeName. I want it to pull in DealerModelName.

[image: Edit view]

**View.cshtml:**

```
@model ModelYearChange.Models.DealerAutoTrim
```

[...]

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DealerAutoID, "DealerAutoID", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("DealerAutoID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DealerAutoID)
        </div>
    </div>
```

**DealerAutoTrimController.cs:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.DealerAutoID = new SelectList(db.DealerAutoes, "DealerAutoID", "DealerMakeName");
        ViewBag.DealerModelName = new SelectList(db.DealerAutoes, "DealerModelName", "DealerModelName");

        return View();
    }

    // POST: /DealerAutoTrim/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "DealerAutoTrimID,DealerAutoID,DealerTrimName,DealerTrimMSRP,DealerTrimMPG_City,DealerTrimMPG_Highway,DealerTrimBulletPoints,Year")] DealerAutoTrim dealerautotrim)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.DealerAutoTrims.Add(dealerautotrim);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.DealerAutoID = new SelectList(db.DealerAutoes, "DealerAutoID", "DealerMakeName", dealerautotrim.DealerAutoID);
        return View(dealerautotrim);
    }
```

Comment: Are you wanting an abstract overview of how this is might be achieved or do you want code? I don't feel like you've really provided enough information to be able to answer this properly. I don't know what your objects are, how they are mapped or how they are related. I don't know what the view looks like or how it will be used.

Comment: Good idea, I will add some code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list binding is kind of messed up :)

Firstly, you only need one SelectList parsed to the View. So in your controller, simply have

```
ViewBag.DealerAutoes = SelectList(db.DealerAutoes, "DealerModelId", "DealerModelName");
```

Note: the second SelectList parameter specifies what field becomes the "value" of the dropdown, with the third parameter defining what field becomes the "text" value.

Then in your view, you can simply have:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DealerAutoId, (SelectList)ViewBag.DealerAutoes)
```

Comment: Works! Thank you. One thing I added in the DropDownListFor is Viewbag.DealerAutoes needs to be cast as a SelectList.

Comment: No problems - have edited my answer to include the cast. Cheers